# World Cup Standings

Tags: combinatorics

In a World Cup Group,there are 4 teams. Each team play against the other 3 once. So, six matches are totally played in a group. A team is awarded 3 points for a win, 1 for draw and 0 for a loss. At the end, how many different standings are possible? How to arrive at the answer?

Comment: By _standing_ you mean a quadruplet of total scores, e.g. (3,3,3,3) (which happens if all matches draw)?

Comment: @heimdall Exactly.

Comment: Are (5,3,2,3) and (2,5,3,3) different standings?

Comment: @Heimdall Sorry.Should have mentioned explicitly.No.

Comment: Maybe first work out how many different ways the group can win/lose/draw, then see if different ways _can_ produce the same standing... Brute force (listing all outcomes) shows there are 5 ways for one to win all 3 group games. It starts: WWW-WWL-WLL-LLL, WWW-WWL-DLL-DLL, WWW-WDL-WDL-LLL, WWW-WLL-WLL-WLL, WWW-DDL-DDL-DDL, WWD-WWD-WLL-LLL, WWD-WWD-DLL-DLL, WWD-WWL-WDL-LLL, ... I'm not sure of a more efficient way of working it out. The only 2 ways to get the same score are WLL and DDD, both making 3.

Comment: There are 40 possible standings here but is there any formula to arrive at?

Comment: I wrote code to find the possible standings for [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2834100). Just code, though, nothing systematic.

Comment: @joriki cool that you informed me - would have not known the answer otherwise. :)